# Node.JS | YouTube Live Stream Detection

Tags: node.js, youtube

In NodeJS, are there any ways to get when a specific YouTube channel goes live? (Like an event or something)

Comment: This isn't about node.js but about what data YouTube exposes through it's APIs. You can go through their documetation to see if the relevant info can be pulled out -  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: yes. The Youtube API has an eventType prop that you can use to query for live videos. You can use Node or any other server backend to make the request